# Don't split when the delimiter is found between square brackets

Tags: excel, csv, delimiter

I created a pipeline in Azure Data Factory which took a MongoDb JSON file as the data source and has been sinked into a CSV file.

When I click on data preview everything looks perfect, but once I actually open the exported CSV in Excel, for some reason Excel doesn't keep the format of one row where there is an array of two email addresses separated by a comma.

Instead of the cell to look like this (Desired Output):

```
EmailAddress
['kate@hotmail.com' , 'katie@hotmail.com']
```

Its displayed like this and puts the second email into the column to the right:

```
EmailAddress
'kate@hotmail.com'
```

Is there a way for Excel to actually open the CSV without doing extra formatting or to ignore delimiters if they are wrapped around `[]`

Note:
This is in the data preview of azure data factory, but in Excel it splits this array because of the `,`
[image]

Comment: Can you maje the square brackets into double-quotes ???

Comment: What do you want the output to display like?

Comment: Can you just make the file pipe-delimited?

Comment: @donPablo I need the array of email addresses to be in one cell because its surrounded by square brackets but because there is a comma between the two email addresses, Excel splits it and puts it in the column to the right.

Comment: @urdearboy I can't make the file pipe delimited because the column delimiter is a comma, so between each record is a comma so thats the only way it can be delimited. Everything looks fine when I preview the data on azure data factory, but once I open the CSV file it then splits the one array which contains two email addresses because of the comma between them, rather than it escaping it because it's contained within square brackets

Comment: I created an XLS with a cell like DesiredOutput.  And then saved it as CSV.  And then used notepad++ to look at the text that was saved, and found  "EmailAddress
['kate@hotmail.com' , 'katie@hotmail.com']"  with doubleQuotes around the entire thing, and with CR LF after EmailAddress to cause the rest to drop down below it in the same cell.  So the surrounding doubleQuotes seem to be the formatting solution.

Comment: very simply, WHEN the cell has an embedded comma, Then change any doubleQuotes to SingleQuotes, and surround the entire cell with DoubleQuotes so that the comma does not create two cells.

Comment: How and where is that supposed to be done? Azure Data Factory?